# Javascript just doesn't redirect, reloads index.html instead

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am trying to make a small dummy login form, that redirects me onto another page when I click a button.
But it just doesn't, instead it reloads the index.html again.

HTML (edit):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Log In</h4>
                    </div> <!-- End of Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="login-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Username" class="form-control" id="login-name">
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- End of -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="login-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" class="form-control" id="login-name">
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- End of -->
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-large" id="loginBtn" style="margin-right: 20px;">Login</button>

                        </div> <!-- End of -->

                    </div> <!-- End of Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Forgot Password</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Sign Up</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    </div> <!-- End of Modal footer -->
                </form>
            </div> <!-- End of Modal Content -->
        </div> <!-- End of Modal Dialog -->
    </div> <!-- End of Modal Fade LOGIN -->
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("load",init, false);

function init() {
    var loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginBtn");
    loginBtn.addEventListener("click", checkLogin, false);
}

function checkLogin(e) {
    alert("FIRED");
    if(1>0){
        window.location.href = "//www.google.com";
    }
}
```

At first I thought maybe it didn't redirect because it didn't call the function at all, but it does. The alert is fired every time, but then it just reloads the page.

It also relocates just fine when I tell it to do it in the init function. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What sort of element is the button? Is it a submit button or anchor that has default behaviour that might reload the page? (The code you show doesn't cancel whatever default behaviour might be associated with a click on the element.)

Comment: Please show us the HTML for your button.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I added it.

Comment: Do you just want to perform a redirect when the button is clicked, or submit the form there?

Comment: For now all I want is to redirect. It is for a uni project, so there are no real credentials yet, everything is just fake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of a `<button>` element is to perform a submit action. Since you're not cancelling it, the form is being submitted and the change you're making to `location.href` is being ignored. Since you haven't specified a value for `action=""`, the submit is just causing the current page to refresh.

Three different ways you can avoid this:

1. Specify `type="button"` on the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-large" 
        id="loginBtn" style="margin-right: 20px;" type="button">Login</button>
```

2. Use an `input` with `type="button"`:

```
<input class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-large" value="Login"
        id="loginBtn" style="margin-right: 20px;" type="button" />
```

3. Prevent the default behavior in your event handler:

```
function checkLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("FIRED");
    if(1>0){
        window.location.href = "//www.google.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so, so much! I didn't know any of that and I couldn't find it anywhere either. That really helped and it is working fine now! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simplier way which I prefer window.location.href in the button tag like this:

```
<button class="Whatever you want to call it" onclick="window.location.href='The_Page_You_Want_To_Redirect_To.html'"></button>
```

And then you can just style the button with CSS as you want it

Comment: No, I really want to keep my documents separate. I think it is better coding style and keeps things tidier. But thank you very much for your help.